# How to configure Dark Reader so that ThunderBird panes are dark?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, configuration, thunderbird, contrast

I'm looking to configure `Thunderbird` so that all three panes are dark, as:

[image: dark thunderbird]

However, after [downloading](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/darkreader/) and adding the `Dark Reader` plugin I get only a single pane dark.  The list of messages is unchanged and still with black writing on a white background, as is the list of folders.

How do I ensure that all three panes are dark as pictured above?

(I use `Dark Reader` with `Firefox` but am certainly open to other such similar plug-in's or add-on's for `Thunder Bird` if they change the appearance.

I'm **not** looking to change how e-mails are sent or composed, simply how they're displayed on my end.)

version:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ thunderbird --version
 Thunderbird 91.5.0
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ uname -a
Linux mordor 5.11.0-49-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 12 17:36:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Comment: Hello. When I lookup Dark Reader it tells me it is only for web browsers and sites you access through them. So in no way has anything to do with the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: using software on Ubuntu is on topic @David

Comment: For me, Thunderbird turns dark in its entirety when selecting the Dark Adwaita theme (but them I am using Vanilla Gnome 40 on Ubuntu 21.10). This probably will work on the forthcoming LTS 22.04.

Comment: @vanadium Hi he is not using a theme he is using a web browser add on.

Comment: @David isn't that an add on intended to make the application dark? I think that one can get Thunderbird entirely dark without any add on.

Comment: @ vanadium The apps web site says it is strictly a browser add on for apps run in the browser. Maybe you can make it dark without the add on but that is not what the OP says he is doing.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong add on!  I searched from within Thunderbird and found the "Dark Reader" add-on for the Thunderbird client.  So far as I know there's no Thunderbird "website" client.